# Advagg and Nginx

Tags: performance, css-js-aggregation

I have the following errors displayed on my status report page:

```
Adv CSS/JS Agg - HTTP Request   HTTP requests to advagg for js files are not getting through.
AdvAgg will issue a request for a file that does not exist inside of the AdvAgg directory. If AdvAgg sends a 404, everything is ok; if something else sends a 404 then that means that AdvAgg will not be able to generate an aggregate if it is missing as something else is handling the 404 before AdvAgg has a chance to do it. If you are reading this, it means that something else is handling the 404 before AdvAgg can. Raw request info:

stdClass Object
(
    [request] => GET /sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__1407579810.js HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.com
Connection: close
Referer: https://www.example.com/admin/reports/status
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)


    [data] => <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

    [protocol] => HTTP/1.1
    [status_message] => Not Found
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
            [date] => Sat, 09 Aug 2014 10:23:31 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html
            [content-length] => 177
            [connection] => close
        )

    [code] => 404
    [error] => Not Found
)
```

and

```
Adv CSS/JS Agg - HTTP Request   HTTP requests to advagg for css files are not getting through.
AdvAgg will issue a request for a file that does not exist inside of the AdvAgg directory. If AdvAgg sends a 404, everything is ok; if something else sends a 404 then that means that AdvAgg will not be able to generate an aggregate if it is missing as something else is handling the 404 before AdvAgg has a chance to do it. If you are reading this, it means that something else is handling the 404 before AdvAgg can. Raw request info:

stdClass Object
(
    [request] => GET /sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__1407579810.css HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.com
Connection: close
Referer: https://www.example.com/admin/reports/status
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)


    [data] => <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

    [protocol] => HTTP/1.1
    [status_message] => Not Found
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
            [date] => Sat, 09 Aug 2014 10:23:31 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html
            [content-length] => 177
            [connection] => close
        )

    [code] => 404
    [error] => Not Found
)
```

I was thinking that this may be due to ubuntu/nginx handling the error messages before drupal could handle it. My questions are:
1. Is it correct?

1. If yes, how can I solve this error?
2. Will making drupal handle all 404 errors create any performance/security implications on the server? Will this improve the performance of the website?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is a link to my present nginx configuration file:

location: /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com.vhost

http://pastebin.com/7Unp0qbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by asking nginx to forward all 404s to drupal so that 404s can be handled at the level of drupal itself. So I added the following to my www.example.com.vhost file located at /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
error_page 404 /index.php
```

This will ensure that all 404s are handled by drupal. This made the error messages to disappear (even though now I am getting a

> Self Request Failure HTTP loopback requests to this server are returning a non positive response code of -1002

error which I think is unrelated).

Answer (score 3):

Workflow of AdvAgg is (as far as I understand) is to create a file URL when it's needed, and create file itself when it's requested.

Your nginx should forward non-existing JS / CSS requests to Drupal. Configure it to do so, and you should be OK.

Comment: This is correct, you can find an example of the appropriate nginx rule [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1951180#comment-8304443)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely add this to your settings.php file.

```
   $conf['advagg_skip_404_check'] = TRUE;
```

It'll definitely help.